# Layout (in HorizontalScrollView) not getting updated on 2nd consecutive layout() with different params

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I have a `RelativeLayout` (a direct child of a `HorizontalScrollView`), which stretches beyond the screen bounds, in which I've placed some views dynamically.

In order to capture a part of the view (as a bitmap), I do the following:

```
v.layout(0, 0, cw, ch);
v.draw(canvas)
```

And then in order to restore the original bounds (which is the full width of the HSV), call `layout()` again, but can also scroll till the *bounds 0->cw* instead of fullWidth.

```
v.layout(0, 0, fullWidth, fullHeight);
v.invalidate();
```

I've already tried all the following approaches and as a desperate measure all their combinations:

```
v.getParent().invalidateChild(v, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));

((Activity)v.getContext()).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();

v.forceLayout();
```

But the layout doesn't update, until I focus on another view (clicking another button/view).

Comment: try a simple `v.requestLayout();`

Comment: Wow!... Thanks a lot. :)
I'm surprised I didn't try it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use simple a `v.requestLayout();`

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()):

> To initiate a layout, call [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()). This method is typically
>   called by a view on itself when it believes that is can no longer fit
>   within its current bounds.

Further great reading: [How Android Draws Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)