# Designing the horizontalScrollView in Different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, androiddesignsupport

I have  layout under which my bottom horizontal scroll view look 
[bottom HorizontalScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfMxl.png)
and want to change it to [new Horizontal Scroll view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLGqu.png)
how i can achieve this where if any item get scroll in scroll view should come at center

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layout (in HorizontalScrollView) not getting updated on 2nd consecutive layout() with different params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780419/layout-in-horizontalscrollview-not-getting-updated-on-2nd-consecutive-layout)

Answer (score 0):

```
    In your activity.xml

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#f00"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 1"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#0f0"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 2"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#00f"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 3"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#ff0"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 4"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#f0f"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 5"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#f90"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 6"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#f00"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 7"
                    android:textColor="#ff9"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#444"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 8"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#ff002211"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 9"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="#0f0"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 10"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>


    **Now add this code in your AndroidManifest.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.gourav.horizontalscrollviewExample" >

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.dhanshri.horizontalscrollviewExample.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>

    **Paste code in strings.xml**


    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">ScrollViewExample</string>
        <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    </resources>


**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: No Dhanshri this is not what i needed please see the photos which I have attached